# How to forward domain/url to website content host, but show old/real/company url?

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, dns

Sorry if some of this is app specific, I'll try to keep it general.

I am administrating a website that uses the UnoEuro webhotel for DNS and I'm using wordpress hosted by wp-engine for the website itself.

More or less "www.MyDomain.com" needs to show the content from "www.wpengine.com/MyDomain", but of course when people go to MyDomain they should not see wpengine/MyDomain.

When I navigate the site it should also happen via MyDomain, like so -> "www.MyDomain.com/SubDomain".
(I think I have this part figured out as the webhotel has an option to "include path in forwarding")

UnoEuro gives me choices between 301 and 302 forwarding, I don't think its related, but I don't know what else to look for.

So GENERALLY speaking how do you do this in most DNS services?

(The reason I need to know is that I am moving the DNS service from an old hotel no longer used and I was not the one who set that up so I don't know how it is done.)

Comment: Generally speaking, you should do the forwarding where you maintain your domain and add an alias by that name to the receiving end. In order to fix the in-site links, add a plugin called "any hostname" to allow the site url to keep the domain name your visitors arrive with. If you run into trouble with either, which you might considering its wpengine, contact their customer support.

Comment: Oh I don't want them to see the link they arrive with, after arriving with MyDomain1 or MyDomain2 it should show the content from wpengine and the MyDomain url and NOT the 1, 2 or wpengine urls.
Thanks for the tips though I will see if I can get further..

Comment: If they type in MyDomain url and it forwards to the right place at wpengine/MyDomain, then you need to change the siteurl in wordpress settings. Regardless, your primary problem is adding the alias MyDomain pointing to wpengine/MyDomain in your wpengine hosting environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution was to add NOT forwarding, but DNS records/bindings that bind the domain to the host IP.

Specifically 3 identical "type A" bindings/ records were added with TTL=150 (DNS update time seconds I think). I don't know why there is 3 identical ones...

It turned out the webhotel had an option to "Import from the current DNS" and then I just changed the mail server IP to the new one.

Comment: Great to hear you got it solved. TTL means time to live, essentially how often it is rechecked in case you decide to point the domain somewhere else at a later time.